# MYISAM can't create table: Row size too large

Tags: restore, mysql-5.6, myisam, table

We are having database in MySQL 5.1, we have taken the DB backup from MySQL 5.1 and trying to restore in MySQL 5.6. We are getting below error:

> ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 603: Row size too large. The maximum row
>   size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This
>   includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some
>   columns to TEXT or BLOBs.

Found the error while creating a table. The table details are below:

1) Table is of type `MyISAM`.

2) Table is having total of 140 columns.

3) Table is having around 105 columns with datatype `varchar(255)`.

4) Table is having 5 columns with datatype `longtext`.

I have done few comparisons/changes, but still I am getting same error:

1) Both the MySQL servers 5.1 and 5.6 are using character set = `latin1`

2) I had converted the `longtext` to `varchar(255)`.

3) I tried to create table with `row_format=dynamic`, but still getting same error.

4) Tried to create the table with `ENGINE=INNODB`, getting same error.

5) converted the `longtext` to `varchar(255)` using `INNODB` engine, getting same error.

6) Found in google to increase `innodb_log_file_size`, which I know it is not concerned to this, still increased to 10 GB and getting same error.

7) I am able to create the table only I create with 98 columns of type varchar(255).

Are there are any other parameters to be changed for creating this table in `MyISAM` ?

I am able to create this table in Linux Environment in MySQL 5.6 and 5.7. But not able to create same table in Windows with either 5.6 or 5.7. I am using Windows 64 bit. What is the difference between Linux and Windows for creating same table ?

Comment: please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637733/mysql-error-code-1118-row-size-too-large-8126-changing-some-columns-to-te  hope it will help

Comment: Hi Ahmad, First I would like to create table in MyISAM. Even, I followed the steps as per the link and changed the innodb_log_file_size to 10GB, still it is not working. Mentioned in step 6.