# MySQL Row Size Too Large (> 8126) with MyISAM tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

We upgraded a MySQL database using MyISAM tables from v5.1 to v5.6 and have a similar situation to [MYISAM can't create table: Row size too large](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128566/myisam-cant-create-table-row-size-too-large). Other questions like this one [Row size too large (> 8126)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90096/row-size-too-large-8126) talk about InnoDB tables.

Row format is already dynamic. It doesn't make sense to change innodb_log_file_size for MyISAM tables, so what is the alternative?

Edits to address issues raised by Rick James:

This is a legacy application, and we have learned a lot since this table was created. However, getting money to make major changes is difficult right now. Converting to InnoDB is an option one day, but probably not right now.

- There are some mediumtext and mediumblob columns.
- It is MyISAM in v5.1 and v5.6.
- The table did not have issues in v5.1.
- We probably didn't specify the character set in either version. I just copied the tables to the new version and ran mysql-upgrade which didn't change anything.
- There are some char and varchar columns.
- The mediumtext columns contain data that was converted to x-UTF-16LE-BOM by Java code (using "UnicodeLittle") before calling setString() on the data in the JDBC driver.

Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `cp_results` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cp_parent_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `errors` text,
  `errors_gz` blob,
  `status` text,
  `status_gz` blob,
  `st_data` mediumtext,
  `st_data_gz` mediumblob,
  `l_stress_vs_hrs` mediumtext,
  `l_stress_vs_hrs_gz` mediumblob,
  `l_allowable_vs_dp` mediumtext,
  `l_allowable_vs_dp_gz` mediumblob,
  `l_outfile` mediumtext,
  `l_outfile_gz` mediumblob,
  `c_data` mediumtext,
  `c_data_gz` mediumblob,
  `timestamp` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `beta_tables_spc_tension` text,
  `beta_tables_spc_tension_gz` blob,
  `cMarginSafety` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_allowable_vs_dp` mediumtext,
  `st_allowable_vs_dp_gz` mediumblob,
  `lMarginSafety` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_fail_hrs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_fail_hrs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `stMarginSafety` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_version` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `l_version` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `c_version` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `m_version` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `m_outfile_gz` mediumblob,
  `matdb_version` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `l_fxf_data_gz` mediumblob,
  `l_ssf_data_gz` mediumblob,
  `st_stress_vs_hrs` mediumblob,
  `st_stress_vs_hrs_gz` mediumblob,
  `st_ssf_data_gz` mediumblob,
  `st_fxf_data_gz` mediumblob,
  `create_timestamp` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_crit_c` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_crit_a` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `c_crit_surface` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `run_version` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_outfile` mediumtext,
  `p_outfile_gz` mediumblob,
  `p_fail_hrs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_version` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `submitter_name` varchar(190) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `submitter_username` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `submitter_system_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `archive_flag` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `temp_ID` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `delete_flag` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delete_timestamp` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `beta_tables_spc_compression_gz` blob,
  `beta_tables_preload_tension_gz` blob,
  `beta_tables_preload_compression_gz` blob,
  `beta_tables_residual_gz` blob,
  `c_rstfile_gz` mediumblob,
  `l_rstfile_gz` mediumblob,
  `st_rstfile_gz` mediumblob,
  `l_cxc_data_gz` mediumblob,
  `st_cxc_data_gz` mediumblob,
  `archived_inputFile_gz` mediumblob,
  `m_rstfile_gz` mediumblob,
  `m_fail_hrs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_plot_file_gz` mediumblob,
  `l_init_hrs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_init_hrs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_init_hrs` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_single_block_dmg` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_cumulative_init_dmg` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_cumulative_dmg` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_cumulative_init_dmg` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_single_block_dmg` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `st_cumulative_dmg` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_timestamp_key` (`cp_parent_ID`,`create_timestamp`),
  KEY `create_timestamp` (`create_timestamp`),
  KEY `submitter_name` (`submitter_name`),
  KEY `submitter_username` (`submitter_username`),
  KEY `submitter_system_id` (`submitter_system_id`),
  KEY `archive_flag` (`archive_flag`),
  KEY `cp_parent_ID` (`cp_parent_ID`),
  KEY `temp_ID` (`temp_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=16824793 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 MAX_ROWS=120000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=68664;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to have "too many" columns in a table or index.  It would be quite handy if you provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table that is giving you trouble.  Here are some guesses; correct me if I am wrong:

- There are a lot of columns.
- No TEXT or BLOB.
- The table is MyISAM in *both* 5.1 and 5.6.
- The table did not have a 8196 problem in 5.1.
- The character set was not specified in 5.1, but defaulted to latin1.
- There may be some CHAR columns.
- The character set was still not specified when creating the table on 5.6.

But 5.6 defaults to utf8, which takes up to 3 bytes per character.  In that case, explicitly add `CHARACTER SET latin1` to each table definition.

(You really should consider migrating to InnoDB.)

**More**

The default `CHARACTER SET` changing from `latin1` to `utf8` is probably the proximate cause.

Looking at the `l_*`, `p_*`, `c_*`, etc columns, I see something of a pattern.  In general it is not wise to splay an array (l/p/c/...) across columns.  I recommend you move those columns to another table.  It would look something like

```
CREATE TABLE misc (
    ID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   -- for JOINing
    type ENUM('l', 'p', 'c', ...) NOT NULL,
    init_hrs ...,
    fail_hrs ...,
    outfile ...,
    rstfile_gz ...,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(ID, type)
);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54787/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-mysql-row-size-too-large-8126-with-myisam).